# How many equivalence classes does this relation have?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I have this relation:

$$A = \mathbb {R} \\ \quad\;\; x\sim y  \iff  x-y \in \mathbb {Z} $$

I have already proved if it is an equivalence relation. Now I am just searching for the equivalence classes of this relation.

How many equivalence classes does this relation have?

Comment: By "amount," do you mean the cardinality?

Comment: Hint: a complete set of representatives would be $[0,1)$.

Comment: $[a] = \{b\in \mathbb{R} \mid b-a\in \mathbb{Z}\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Even more understandable, I think: $[a] = a+\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 1):

Every equivalence class has a unique representant $r\in[0,1)$:

$$[r]=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x=\lfloor x\rfloor+r\}$$